# Oracle Calling URL to send Text Message

Tags: oracle, plsql, sms-gateway

Can any body guide how to calling http API inside Oracle database.  What i want to do is i want to sent lot of text messages inside the Oracle API... But i don't want to open http socket many times.  [SMS Text API Documentation](http://www.innovativetxt.com/services/sms_api_gateway.htm)  can be seen at below link.

http://www.innovativetxt.com/services/sms_api_gateway.htm

Please advice me method that i don't open http socket again and again ... for each message.

Comment: Does the API you are trying to call support sending multiple messages via a single HTTP connection?  My guess is that it would.  If so, it would be helpful to post a link to the specific documentation about how the service expects to accept multiple messages since there probably aren't a lot of people that are intimately familiar with your chosen SMS gateway.

Comment: Have you looked at the  UTL_HTTP package -http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_http.htm

Comment: Yes, URL_HTTP is the solution i was looking for.. !

Answer (score 1):

The UTL_HTTP package makes Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) callouts from SQL and PL/SQL. You can use it to access data on the Internet over HTTP.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_http.htm